# Show the Result like

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My table is like this:

```
Sitecode    Month  Amount
--------    -----  ------
XX          Jan     1000
XX          Jan     3000
XX          Apr     3000
XX          Apr     1000
```

What I want is, to show the result something like this:

```
Sitecode    MonthJAN   MonthAPR
--------    --------   --------
XX          1000       3000
XX          3000       1000
```

Comment: which db it is ??? use pivot

Comment: provide tables schemes, it seems that you want to show joined data from 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT clause:

[Pivot tables in SQL Server. A simple sample.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this using [`PIVOT`.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

[**Fiddler Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31076/1)

```
CREATE TABLE Sample
(
    SiteCode VARCHAR(100),  
    Month VARCHAR(100),    
    Amount INT
)

INSERT INTO Sample VALUES('XX', 'Jan', 1000)
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES('XX', 'Jan', 3000)  
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES('XX', 'Apr', 3000)
INSERT INTO Sample VALUES('XX', 'Apr', 1000)

SELECT P.SiteCode, P.Jan AS MonthJan, P.Apr AS MonthApr FROM 
(
    SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Month] ORDER BY [Month]) AS Num 
    FROM Sample
) AS A
PIVOT (MAX(A.Amount) FOR A.Month IN ([Jan], [Apr])) AS P
```